# How can I set my model relationships to do the following in .NET Core 3.1 & EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm in the middle of learning .NET Core 3.1 and EF and decided to start my own project. I've been wanting to set up my models so that I can create the following relationships:

**User** `-1-to-Many->` **Event** `-1-to-many->` **EventMember** `-1-to-many->` **User**

I created an **Event** API to test my changes but had no luck.

I was envisioning the JSON token to look like the following:

```
"Event" {
        "id" :
        "name" :
        "userId" :
        "eventMember" : {
                          "id" :
                          "eventId" : 
                          "UserId" :
                          "user" : {
                                    "id" :
                                    "name" :
                                   }
                                   {
                                    "id" :
                                    "name" :
                                   }
                                   {
                                    "id" :
                                    "name" :
                                   }

                        }

                        {
                          "id" :
                          "eventId" : 
                          "user" : {
                                    "id" :
                                    "name" :
                                   }
                                   {
                                    "id" :
                                    "name" :
                                   }
                                   {
                                    "id" :
                                    "name" :
                                   } 


                        }



       }
```

User.cs

```
User {

public int Id {Get; Set;}
public string Name{Get; Set;}

public ICollection<Event> Event {Get; Set;}

}
```

Event.cs

```
Event {

public int Id {Get; Set;}
public string Name{Get; Set;}

public int UserId {Get; Set;}
public User User {Get; Set;}

public ICollection<EventMember> EventMember {Get; Set;}

}
```

EventMember.cs

```
EventMember {

public string Id {Get; Set;}
public string Name{Get; Set;}

//This is where I'm not sure How I would go about the relationship to User
public User User {Get; Set;}

}
```

Here are my questions:

1. There's is a circular dependency here, is that bad practice?
2. Would it be better to keep **User** independent from the other models and just populate the userId in the Event table manually in the controller?
3. If I get the relationships setup correctly, when I call my Event API, will EF return the result with the other nested objects, such as EventMember and User automatically, or is this something I have to populate manually, example: `event.EventMember = _eventMemberRepository.FirstOfDefault(MyEventMemberId); //Something like that, basically call the repo to get the object and populate it in the parent object`

But most importantly, what is the proper way to setup the models for this relationships in EF? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks All.

Comment: I'm confused. Why 1 EventMember can have many users? Your relationship looks like many-to-many between User and Event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your demand , I think that the relationships between User, Event and EventMember are : User and EventMember (Many-to-many), Event and EventMember(one-to-many), The below is a demo:

Model and DbContext

```
  public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserEventMember> UserEventMembers { get; set; }
}

public class UserEventMember
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public string EventMemberId { get; set; }
    public EventMember EventMember { get; set; }
}
public class EventMember
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public Event Event { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserEventMember> UserEventMembers { get; set; }

}
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EventMember> EventMember { get; set; }
}

public class MVCDbContext:DbContext
{
    public MVCDbContext(DbContextOptions<MVCDbContext> options):base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Event { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EventMember> EventMember { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserEventMember>()
            .HasKey(ue => new { ue.UserId,ue.EventMemberId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserEventMember>()
            .HasOne(ue=>ue.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.UserEventMembers)
            .HasForeignKey(ue=>ue.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserEventMember>()
            .HasOne(ue => ue.EventMember)
            .WithMany(e => e.UserEventMembers)
            .HasForeignKey(ue => ue.EventMemberId);
    }
}
```

Controller, use the [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) method to specify related data to be included in query results.

```
 public IActionResult GetEventData()
    {
        var model = _context.Event
            .Include(e => e.EventMember)
                .ThenInclude(em => em.UserEventMembers)
                .ThenInclude(ue => ue.User)
            .Select(e=>new { 
                Id=e.Id,
                Name=e.Name,
                EventMember=e.EventMember.Select(em=>new { 
                    em.Id,em.Name,em.EventId,
                    User=em.UserEventMembers.Select(ue=>new { 
                        Id=ue.UserId ,
                        Name=ue.User.Name
                    }).ToList(),
                }).ToList()
            })
            .ToList();
        return Json(model);
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

what you describing is exactly many-to-many relationship between **event** and **user**
you can read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

This will be the sample for your case

```
User {

public int Id {Get; Set;}
public string Name{Get; Set;}

public ICollection<EventMember> EventMembers {Get; Set;}

}

Event {

public int Id {Get; Set;}
public string Name{Get; Set;}

public ICollection<EventMember> EventMembers {Get; Set;}

}

EventMember {

public int UserId {Get; Set;}
//optional
public User User{Get; Set;}

public int EventId {Get; Set;}
//optional
public Event Event{Get; Set;}

}
```

you also need to provide the mapping in your dbcontext class for this relationship

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EventMember>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.EventId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<EventMember>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Event)
            .WithMany(p => p.EventMember)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EventMember>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.User)
            .WithMany(t => t.EventMember)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.EventId);
```